# How do I loop after each answer is printed in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Do I add a "for" loop here and how? I want the program to repeat itself.

```
print('Ask a question')
import random

messages = ['It is certain',
    'It is decidedly so',
    'Yes definitely',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'Concentrate and ask again',
    'My reply is no',
    'Outlook not so good',
    'Very doubtful']

print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])
```

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do in your loop

Comment: It's an 8-Ball. So I want an answer to print and then ask  'Ask a question' and loop to messages - Thanks

Comment: So you want it to print a random message from messages?

Comment: No. I want it to print 'Ask a question' after print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magic 8-ball (question & answer)**

Minimal changes to posted code

```
import random
from random import randint

messages = ['It is certain',
    'It is decidedly so',
    'Yes definitely',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'Concentrate and ask again',
    'My reply is no',
    'Outlook not so good',
    'Very doubtful']

while True:
  question = input("What is your question? ")
  if question:
    print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])
  else:
    break
```

**Even Better but equivalent while loop**

```
while input("What is your question? "):
  print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])
```

**Use random.choice**

[random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

Simplifies random message selection from list

```
while input("What is your question? "):
  print(random.choice(messages))
```

Comment: So this is what I am trying to do - Program starts with "Ask a question" - User types input - (example) Do I understand Python? - User hits 'enter or return' key -  Answer from random.randint prints w/ Answer - program prints  "Ask a question" - the loop ensues

Comment: Nice work - You nailed it - I will study more regarding "while True"

Comment: Nice work - You nailed it - I will study more regarding "while True" DarrylG sorry for the comment before this one I see you had the answer but I was too stupid to see it. Waw was was... If you have any work I could look at that uses the "while True" loop that you have used or written please feel free to throw me another bone or link as it were. Thanks - Good work!

Comment: @PeterCockram--I updated my answer with another version using the while loop.  This is shorter since it has the condition as part of the while loop.  However, the run should be equivalent to the first (i.e. both stop when the person enters a blank line).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in messages:
        print(i)
```

This will loop through message and print the variable message

Comment: Thanks but the answer was a bit more complicated and it turned out to be a While True loop pointed out from DarrylG. Notice he showed where to put the code along with the provided code giving his answer context - All the same, Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

To print a random message for messages on each play you can write like this, see code comments:

```
import random

messages = ['It is certain',
    'It is decidedly so',
    'Yes definitely',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'Concentrate and ask again',
    'My reply is no',
    'Outlook not so good',
    'Very doubtful']

user_input = ""
print ("Press enter to play or q + enter to quit")
# while user input doesn't equal q
while user_input != "q":
    # print a random message
    print(messages[random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)])
    # ask for user input
    user_input = input()
```

Comment: Very nice work - and I will study your answer - But I am looking for a question to print and then an answer - giving the user a chance to ask a different question. But thanks, all the same, I like your approach but I am learning and I'm after a certain solution - Hell I thought I needed a "for" loop. I am newbie extraordinaire. LOL